# window.postMessage is firing multiple times in angular Onint function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm Facing an issue with the window.postMessage is firing multiple times whenever I returned to that component so I would like to get a solution for this issue. Thank you.

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.service.userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails'))
  window["ReactNativeWebView"] && window["ReactNativeWebView"].postMessage(JSON.stringify({"change": false}))
  console.log("notifyReact")
  if(this.service.userDetails==null)
    this.router.navigate(['health/login'])
  else {
    this.getPatientList()
    this.getDoctorList()
  }
```

}

Comment: ngOnInit hook is executed when the component is created, that's how it works. You would like to get a solution, but what is the problem what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: we are trying to send postmessage to native app.but window['ReactNativeWebView].postmessage is throwing same message multiple times insted of one time whenever that component loads or click event happens .

Answer (score 0):

Well, ngOnInit is fired every time the component intializes, so whenever you return to it that piece of code is going to be executed.

An easy solution would be having a little service injected in root that holds a variable such as:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService
    initialized: boolean = false;
}
```

and then in your component:

```
constructor(private myService:MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.userDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails'))
    if(!myService.initialized) {
        window["ReactNativeWebView"] && window["ReactNativeWebView"].postMessage(JSON.stringify({"change": false}))
        console.log("notifyReact")
        myService.initialized = true;
    }
    if(this.service.userDetails==null)
        this.router.navigate(['health/login'])
    else {
        this.getPatientList()
        this.getDoctorList()
}
```

Comment: it's not working...if that post message call on load of component that will be ok  but that is throwing/firing same post message multiple times that is a issue that has to fire once on load or route change.